# Guidelines for cooking Desert Truffels?

Tags: truffles

I have gotten my hands on a number of fresh blackish Desert Truffles, which are apparently quite different from the European ones. To [quote](http://syrianfoodie.blogspot.ie/2010/03/desert-truffles.html):

> Desert truffles have nothing to do with their European cousins in
>   terms of taste, texture and aroma. Kemeh is more like dense mushrooms
>   rather than the truffles you know.

I'm looking for some guidelines on how to cook with them not for recipes, as this is the first time I'll be using them. I'm looking for guidelines that will emphasize their flavor such as "use and grate fresh" or perhaps "cook with the peels as well".

---

For those wondering what they look like after scrubbing off the sand:

[image]

Comment: Hello nbubis, I know that feeling of having a new ingredient in your kitchen. But the problem is, we cannot give you guidance which recipe to choose. Also, there are no single guidance on "how to cook them" if you don't have a preparation in mind. Once you have chosen a recipe to try, if its instructions are not sufficient, you can come here with concrete questions. But they have to be about solving a problem you are having, not a "I don't have a goal" situation.

Comment: @rumtscho - If you know from experience that I can use it for everything just like a regular mushroom, please say so. However, I've read that for other types of truffle it is suggested to only / grate / lightly sauté / not overcook etc. I'm looking for similar guidelines. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @rumtscho - Edited the question to fit the guidelines. Care to re-open?

Comment: thanks for editing, I reopened The other part was indeed the one going mostly against the rules. I don't know if the guidelines you are looking for exist in that form, but if they do, I hope you will get them now.